# paramiko exception for connection refused

Tags: python, exception, paramiko

```
import paramiko
try:
    ssh =paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname='10.10.1.0',username='test',password='test1234')
    print 'Successfully connected'
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print "Authentication failed, please verify your credentials"
except paramiko.SSHException as sshException:
    print "Unable to establish SSH connection: %s" % sshException
```

This is my code. It was working fine.
If i give wrong userid and password - Perfectly throwing expection.

But when hostname is not valid, it's throwing error as "Connection refused" and not sure what type of exception have to raise. Could some please help.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 290, in connect
    sock.connect(addr)
  File "<string>", line 1, in connect
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.error` is spelled `socket_error` like this:

```
from socket import error as socket_error
```

and then:

```
try:
    # as you were
except socket_error as socket_err:
    # do something
```

The error message is telling you about error numbers (`socket_err.errno`) so you can check that e.g. compare to `errno.ECONNREFUSED`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
import errno

try:
    # Do something
except socket.error, v:
    e_code = v[0]
    if e_code == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
        print "Connection Refused"
```